# GNU Make: how can I set up two or more dependency targets within a single define..endef block?

Tags: dependencies, user-defined-functions, gnu-make

I'm trying to set up multiple dependencies within a single GNU Make define..endef block, but I'm having no luck at all. If I strip the problem down to a basic form, I'm aiming for a final makefile that looks like this:

```
all:    CPU1    CPU2

CPU1: Build_CPU1

CPU2: Build_CPU2

Build_CPU1:
    @echo Building CPU #1

Build_CPU2:
    @echo Building CPU #2
```

The problem comes if I try to put the two intermediate dependencies inside a define..endef block:

```
all:    CPU1    CPU2

define DoBuild =
CPU1:   Build_CPU1



CPU2:   Build_CPU2



endef

$(call DoBuild)

Build_CPU1:
    @echo Building CPU #1

Build_CPU2:
    @echo Building CPU #2
```

If I put a bare newline after each of the two :-dependency lines (i.e. "CPU1:   Build_CPU1" and "CPU2:  Build_CPU2") in the define..endef block, GNU Make complains about "*** target pattern contains no '%'". But if I add in a space-then-newline after the two dependencies, that error message goes away.

However, having followed the two dependency lines with space-then-newline, GNU Make complains about "*** multiple target patterns."

What I'm pretty sure is happening here is that GNU Make is collapsing all the lines of the define..endef block into a single line: and, of course, you can't have multiple colons on a single line.

According to the GNU Make manual 6.8 ("Defining Multi-Line Variables"), you should be able to force a newline inside a define..endef block by using two newlines. However, the problem with this seems to be that this is ultimately defining a single variable, and so is being parsed as if it were a single line, even though it contains newlines. Which is (I think) why it is collapsing the two dependencies into a single line (placing both the colons on a single line), so I'm basically out of ideas. :-(

Is there any way of convincing GNU Make to define two or more dependency targets within a single define..endef block?

PS: I'm using GNU Make 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a working example:

```
all: CPU1 CPU2

define DoBuild # No equal sign is needed.
CPU1: Build_CPU1
    @echo $$@
CPU2: Build_CPU2
    @echo $$@
endef

$(eval $(call DoBuild)) # Use eval.

Build_CPU1:
    @echo $@

Build_CPU2:
    @echo $@
```

Note that `call` returns a string. To make that string a part of the makefile [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-eval) is required.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, you're a star! :-)